# Get username in constructor for controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that gets data based on current user that is logged in. And I would like to assign a local variable like this:

```
    public UsergroupsCustAdminController()
    {

        User u = _us.GetUsers(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).First();

        this._customerID = u.CustomerID;
    }
```

Somehow I cant get the value for current user logged in. How should I fix this? I need to use that "CustomerID" in lots of places in my controllerclass.

/M

Answer (score -2, accepted):

found answer on:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx

Comment: Please explain what the answer was and give a code sample. A SO answer should stand alone without the source article. Although naming your reference is good practice too.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to hook in too early. Suggest you override `OnActionExecuting` and put this code in there, like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    User u = _us.GetUsers(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).First();
    this._customerID = u.CustomerID;
}
```

Comment: You have some example where it shows how I can pass that variable in?

Comment: @belugabob - Absolutely right, and I am a stickler for this myself. Not a clue how that got through (if you check my list of edits you'll see many spelling, grammar and punctuation fixes). +1 for catching me out. :)